# Нужно ли обособлять обороты с предлогом «за исключением»?

Tags: пунктуация, предлоги

Я была уверена, что нужно. Почему?  Вот пример: *Пришли все, за исключением двух-трех человек.*  Исключение нужно как-то  **выделить ударением, подчеркнуть**,  так как  первая часть фразы  без второй части будет неверной.  Вот и Розенталь говорит о том, что оборот с "кроме" **в значении исключения** всегда обособляется, тогда и оборот с предлогом "за исключением" тоже надо бы обособлять. Да и **на практике** мне обычно встречались варианты с обособлением.

Однако наши классики этот предлог **никак не выделяют** среди остальных. **Розенталь** говорит, что обособление для большинства предлогов факультативно, уделяя особое внимание только предлогам *кроме* и *вместо*. Лопатин  тоже не рассматривает этот предлог отдельно, но у него контроль над всеми необособленными оборотами **строгий**. Обороты должны обязательно обособляться в начале предложения,  не должны разделять подлежащее и сказуемое или мешать управлению.  Свобода выбора  остается  только в конце фразы.

Итак, я была уверена, что **никогда не встречусь** с необособленным оборотом «за исключением» ― уж этот оборот обособляется всегда. Но, увы, "всегда" никогда не случается. Нацкорпус до поры до времени подтверждал мое мнение, но **исключения всё-таки нашлись,** причем  три примера явно **противоречили правилам Лопатина**.  Может быть, ошибка корректоров?  Но приглядевшись, я нашла  им некоторые оправдания.

**И вопросы:** А как вы относитесь к предлогу «за исключением»?  Нужно ли его выделять среди остальных или обособление действительно факультативное?  Можно ли не обособлять обороты в приведенных примерах?

(1) Все гимназисты нашего города **за исключением** ришельевцев носили форму чёрного цвета; ришельевцы ― серого. [В. П. Катаев, (1975-1977)]

(2) У неё опыта **за исключением** нескольких месяцев практики ещё нет, но и её непременно возьмут. [О. В. Демидов, МММ, 2013]

(3) Внутри он  (Белый дом, здание обкома) был сплошь красным и полированным **за исключением** огромной белой головы Ленина в фойе. [В. А. Ярмолинец, 2008]

(4) Но есть и другие, ничем не опасные (красавицы), и вот возникает одна из них — веснушчатая соседка Анна…  Анна ввергает вас в помешательство первым же взмахом своих ресниц…Так произошло и со мной. **За исключением веснушек** все приблизительно совпадало. Да и жила она неподалеку, в детстве мы не раз с нею сталкивались. [Леонид Зорин, 2006]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Факультативность по Розенталю я понимаю не как дозволение применять её произвольно, по авторскому предпочтению. Первый и четвертый примеры без обособления я воспринимаю благожелательно - вероятно потому, что сочетания "все гимназисты за исключением таких-то" и "всё за исключением веснушек" (в исходном предложении, однако, я бы принял во внимание иной порядок слов - и возможно, поступил бы "по Лопатину") обладают законченностью, выражая часть целого, и при этом выступают как **единый член предложения**. Этого нельзя сказать о конструкциях "опыт, за исключением нескольких месяцев практики" или "сплошь... за исключением белой головы", где образ *частного* создается развернутыми конструкциями, для которых требуется пунктуация, условно говоря, "по обстановке". Надо полагать, корректоры этих двух литераторов понимают факультативность иначе, чем я.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. Я нашла примерам такое оправдание. В сложном предложение (1)  ударением выделяются слова  «ришельевцев». «ришельевцы», поэтому оборот в первом части нежелательно обособлять.  В сложном предложении (2) ударением выделяются слова «нет», «возьмут», поэтому  обособление оборота также помешает их сопоставлению. В предложении (3) причина нашлась с трудом;  здесь, вероятно, читатель должен обратить внимание на противопоставление  красного и белого цвета (Белый дом, красный внутри, и белая голова Ленина как оправдание названия).

Comment: Предложение (4) нераспространенное, оборот входит в основное сообщение. Таким образом, структура предложение управляет и этим оборотом тоже.  Он просто чаще обособляется в соответствии со своей структурой, но автор не выделяет оборот, если  обособление мешает правильной расстановке ударений.

Comment: И еще личное впечатление. Мне не жаль времени, потраченного на подробное изучение этих предложений.  Я убедилась, что существует много интересных книг об уже ушедшем историческом времени – написанных хорошим языком и незаслуженно забытых. Сейчас писатели пишут по-другому:  жизнь обычных людей  не вызывает у них интереса, без элемента фантастики литература  никак не может обойтись. В этом мне видится определенная потеря художественного мастерства.  И еще что-то искусственное, ненастоящее,  но необходимое для поддержания интереса читателей.